# JSDoc overriding typedef properties

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

In the example below I would like the FirstComponent to have data of type string[], but it's just any from BaseComponent.

```
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *  data: any
 * }} BaseComponent
 */

/**
 * @typedef {{
 *  data: string[]
 * } & BaseComponent} FirstComponent
 */
```

Is there any way around that behavior? I don't want types to merge, but override instead. So the & operator probably won't do the job. There is also other syntax available for JSDoc: https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html I would be happy to get any of these working but I feel like there might be no solution.

Btw I'm using VS Code.